# Hosting Laravel Filament apache server responded with a MIME type of ""

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, xampp, laravel, mime-type

I been trying to host my laravel filament project into my server using apache but upon deployment i met 2 problem i never seen before

[pic related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6HzM.png)

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

and

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://103.179.216.68/js/filament/forms/components/select.js?v=3.0.0.0`

this is my apache vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/Infakin-2.0/public"
    ServerName panelinfakin.ictitlmi.info
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/Infakin-2.0/public">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and last when development using artisan serve the problem isn't appearing so that's make me suspicius there's a problem with my xampp apache, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: If your project includes javascript then you should checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935119/set-my-js-mime-type-to-text-javascript , to enable .js meme type in apache

Comment: thank you so much for answering i just did what in stackoverlow told me to do and basically no luck, i both use the first answer in my apache vhost config and the second in my mime config apache still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Silakan dicoba dengan menggunakan htaccess berikut:


Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle MIME type for JavaScript files
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
    ForceType 'text/javascript'
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Please note that this site is an English-language-only site. Please use a translator utility if you are not able to rewrite this answer yourself in English.